# What kind of statistical test should/could I perform in this set of data to detect an increase in email usage?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, frequency

What kind of statistical test should/could I perform on this set of data ?
Its done on the same group of 50 people before and after intervention.
Any possible tests that could be done with this data are welcome, t-test, chi-square etc. What kind of test fit these specific kind of variables.The goal is to detect if the usage of email has been increased after the intervention.
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your scientific question and hypothesis about change?

Comment: Do you have data on each person or just the tables above?

Comment: I have data on each person on many questions like the one above. But they all have this format. Categorical but escalating possible answers to choose, like "never,rarely,often and very often". My goal is to detect an increase/decrease in the usage of communication methods and sites. Email just happens to be in the example I gave.@PeterFlom